# (python) execute function every x seconds

Tags: python, multithreading

this is my source code that executes function every 1 seconds

buy, it only executes one times.

**In short, I want to get the `#` of line from the named pipe output every seconds**

Is there any suggestion for this problem?

thank you for your help in advance

```
class Monitor:
    def __init__(self, namedpipe, name):
        self.namedpipe = namedpipe
        self.name = name
        self.count = 0
    def run(self):
        print self.name+" start run"
        while True:
            line = self.namedpipe.readline()
            self.count = self.count+1
    def getCost(self):
        print "Hi"


while True:
    line = monitor.readline()
    line = line.strip()
    if not line: 
        ans =raw_input('stop?')
        if ans=='y': break
    monitorList = open(line, 'r')
    m = Monitor(monitorList, line)
    thread.start_new_thread(m.run, ())
    time.sleep(1)
    threading.Timer(0.1, m.getCost).start()
```

Answer (score 1):

With Threading.Timer, you have to restart the timer each time it has expired - so during the execution of the function called when the timer expires - m.getCost in your code - the timer has to be started again. You might want to define a wrapper function to do this work, to avoid polluting m.getCost() with timer stuff.

Comment: No, that's not the job of this function. There should be a wrapper function which does this.

Comment: However, you code it, when the timer expires it calls a function - if you want a timer to run again then somewhere in the execution of that function you have to start the timer.